# Spring WebClient in Kotlin; how to log response body if response can not be deserialised

Tags: kotlin, webclient

I am calling an external service in kotlin using WebClient

Summary of the requirements based on response;

- Response status = 4xx or 5xx -> only request should be logged
- Response status = 2xx BUT response can not be deserialised -> both
  request and response body should be logged
- Response status = 2xx and deserialisation is successful (all is fine), no logging needed

I am a java developer and having difficulties in kotlin. Right now I could come up with below code

```
fun getMyResponse(
        params....
    ): ResponseDto<ResponseDto.Operations.CustomerAddress> {
        return circuitBreaker.executeCallable {
            val request = RequestDto.build(params...)
            webClient.post()
                    .uri("/rest_api/v1/adress")
                    .bodyValue(request)
                    .exchangeToMono {clientResponse ->
                        if (!clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful) {
                            throw RuntimeException("Failed to fetch data: ${clientResponse.statusCode()}")
                        }
                        clientResponse.bodyToMono<ResponseDto<ResponseDto.Operations.CustomerAddress>>()
                                .onErrorResume {error: Throwable ->
                                    log.error("Invalid response. Request:{}", request) // I need to log response as well.
                                    Mono.error(error)
                                }
                    }
                    .block()
        }
    }
```

How can log the response in onErrorResume method or is there a better way of doing it?